# set method works fine in Remix browser (with Test-RPC) but out VM out of gas error while using web3 object

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, remix, out-of-gas

When I try to use this call this method in remix browser it gets mined.

```
//addAsset function adds an asset along with an owner
    function addAsset(address newOwner,bytes32 description, uint cost) returns(string) {
        if (msg.sender == issuer) {
            assetCount++;
            Asset memory tempAsset = Asset(assetCount,newOwner,description,cost);
            setAssetOwnership(newOwner,assetCount,tempAsset);
            return "asset created";
    } else { 
        return "you are not the owner of contract";
    }
    }
```

But when I call the same method in the browser via web3 object, I get this.

[image: VM exception out of gas error]

```
    <script>
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        var web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } 
        else 
        {
            // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
            var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
        }                 

        console.log(web3);

        web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
        var vishContract = web3.eth.contract(CONTRACT-OPCODE);

//trying to increase the gas limit here, not sure if its correct
// var contract = vishContract.at('CONTRACT ADDRESS', {gasLimit: "10000000"}); 
        var contract = vishContract.at('CONTRACT ADDRESS');

        function getIssuerId(){
                 document.getElementById("issuerId").innerText = contract.issuer();
        }
</script>
```

I saw similar questions posted, most of them were resolved by changing string to bytes32 or it was mentioned that their contract is huge, mine isn't.

I am still fairly new with smart contracts. Can anyone please help me out here?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

**Check if you have sufficient ETH** from the account you're calling the contract.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below:

```
var contract = vishContract.at('CONTRACT ADDRESS', {gas: "10000000"});
```

instead of

```
var contract = vishContract.at('CONTRACT ADDRESS', {gasLimit: "10000000"});
```